# stop redirecting page if alert appears

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see many questions here but no one solve my issue.

i have a form and a save button, when click on save button it run a script first to check if bad words are used. If text contain bad words, it shows an alert.when i click `ok` of alert, it perform pending action of `save` button and then redirect to main page.

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).delegate('.btn-save-template', 'click', function() {
    var text = $('#input-message').val().toLocaleLowerCase(); 
    var bad_words = ['bad', 'sex', 'fuck you', 'fuckyou', 'murder', 'rap']; // Bad Words

    if((new RegExp( '\\b' + bad_words.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b') ).test(text)){
        alert('Sorry, you are not allowed to use bad words');
    }
});
</script>
```

But, I want to stay at the same page after alert, so user can remove bad word and click save button again.

Comment: First: don't use `delegate` anymore as it is deprecated, use `.on()` instead, secondly: have a look at [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) this will help you. Prevent the default action of the form submit and only submit the form manually if the check was negative or the other way round, prevent the form submit if the check was positiv

Comment: @empiric i use this e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return false;  but didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `keydown` function of jquery to check bad words and disable button if bad word is used.

My Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#input-message').keydown(function() {
    var text = $('#input-message').val().toLocaleLowerCase(); 
    var bad_words = ['bad', 'fuck you', 'fuckyou', 'kill you', 'murder', 'rap']; // Bad Words

    if((new RegExp( '\\b' + bad_words.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b') ).test(text)){
        alert('Sorry, you are not allowed to use bad words');
        $('.btn-save-template').attr('disabled',true);
        $('input-messgae').css('border','1px solid red');
    }else{
        $('.btn-save-template').attr('disabled',false);
    }
});
</script>
```

Now it works fine for me... :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace **submit** type of button with **button** type to disable form processing by browser.

```
<input type="button" class="btn-save-template" value=...>
```

When user clicks on the button, submit the form from the script, if all tests passed successfuly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).delegate('.btn-save-template', 'click', function() {
    var text = $('#input-message').val().toLocaleLowerCase(); 
    var bad_words = ['bad', 'sex', 'fuck you', 'fuckyou', 'murder', 'rap']; // Bad Words

    if((new RegExp( '\\b' + bad_words.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b') ).test(text)){
        alert('Sorry, you are not allowed to use bad words');
    } else {
        this.form.submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default behavior of the browser

```
function(event) {
   ...
   if((new RegExp( '\\b' + bad_words.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b') ).test(text)){
       alert('Sorry, you are not allowed to use bad words');
       event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```